# What kind of ML algorithm should be done for the question below?

Tags: regression, pca

I have a regression problem of a `feature` and a `target` which seems to be done by algorithms such as `linear regression`, `multi-layer perceptron` etc. The image below seems to be the final result as the linear regression needs just `mean-squared error` and its `coefficients`.
[image]

But on the other hand, also these two axes are highly correlated to some other thing and the process can not be generalized. I was wondering if `PCA` can be good or useful for this problem or not.
To make it a little bit clear the dataset is like below:

```
Time step1

feature 1       | feature 2            | feature 3 | feature 4 |
constantValue 1 |constantValue 1       |   x1      |     y1    |
...
constantValue 1 |constantValue 1       |   x1000   |     y1000 |

Time step2

feature 1       | feature 2            | feature 3 | feature 4 |
constantValue 2 |constantValue 2       |   x1      |     y1    |
...
constantValue 2 |constantValue 2       |   x1000   |     y1000 |

Time step3

feature 1       | feature 2            | feature 3 | feature 4 |
constantValue 3 |constantValue 3       |   x1      |     y1    |
...
constantValue 3 |constantValue 3       |   x1000   |     y1000 |
```

The constant values of features 1 and 2 are different from each other but they are all repeated for 1000 rows of features 3 and 4. The goal is to find a distinctive behavior for each group which seems to be a classification problem while doing a regression for each of which is the only thing that can be done because it can give me `MSE` and by comparing it, we can classify it but I think doing something like `Clustering`, `PCA` or using `Unsupervised learning` methods can help me out.

Comment: I can't tell what's actually going on here. Please explain *concretely* (i) what your data set is (ii) what you hope to achieve (iii) what you have tried and (iv) why you are not satisfied with what you have already tried

Comment: @jcken you were right, I tired to make it a bit clear, and I hope I did well